# How to set txture to top left of screen

Tags: directx, textures, directx-11

I'm trying to render a 960x540 texture in 1920x1080 screen, and want to set the picture at top left corner.So I changed the vertex buffer ,but It doesn't seem to work.Is there any method could achive this?Thanks in advance!

```
Vertex s_vertexData[4] =
    {
        { { -1.0f,  -1.0f, -0.5f, 1.0f }, { 0.f, 1.f } },
        { {  0.0f,  -1.0f, -0.5f, 1.0f }, { 1.f, 1.f } },
        { { 0.0f,  0.0f,  0.5f, 1.0f }, { 1.f, 0.f } },
        { { -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.5f, 1.0f }, { 0.f, 0.f } },
    };
    initialData.pSysMem = s_vertexData;
    bufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(s_vertexData);
    bufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
    bufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    bufferDesc.StructureByteStride = sizeof(Vertex);

    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        device->CreateBuffer(&bufferDesc, &initialData,
            m_spVertexBuffer.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()));
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't work' exactly?  BTW, you may want to look at [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/main/PCSamples/IntroGraphics/SimpleTexturePC).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! "Dosen't work" means the picture is still at the center not the top left corner.I'm already referring to this sample but still don't know how to change the texture position.May be Vertex Buffer can't do this?@ChuckWalbourn

Comment: What did you do with ``RSSetViewport``?

Comment: m_screenViewport = CD3D11_VIEWPORT(
            0.0f,
            0.0f,
            static_cast<float>(800),
            static_cast<float>(600)
        ); context->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport); So I should change the viewport?

Comment: The viewport needs to exactly match the dimensions of the render target. Is the render target 800 x 600?

Comment: I changed the viewport dimensions to match texture, and Viewport does work!Thank u very much!